# Voted approved-is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> The plan was voted approved.

This sentence rings a strange note in my head. Is this sentence acceptable? I came up with the sentence, but I am not sure how I can use vote in a passive manner and still maintain the point that it was not voted against, but for.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's grammatical, but I agree that it rings strange. Here are a couple ways you could get around the strangeness:

> - The plan was voted on and approved.
> - The plan was approved after a committee vote.
> - The committee voted to approve the plan.

I've said "committee" in these examples, but you could substitute *board, Senate, panel*, or the like.

Comment: Thank you! Can you think of any reason why it sounds so strange?

Comment: It sounds strange because you don't **vote a plan approved** and it sounds like some things that do work like that, grammar-wise: to find the door open or see the project finished. Also, vote doesn't take a direct object, usually. To vote something in, out or vote on something, as J.R. has written.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is grammatical

> The plan was voted approved.

additional context is necessary for it not to sound awkward

> Q: Was the plan **Approved** or **Rejected**?
>   A: The plane was voted **Approved**.

Usually it would expressed as

> They **approved** the plan.

without the additional context it sounds like you are *trying to say*

> The plan was **voted** *(on)* and **approved**.

which is what a native speaker would expect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would just like to ask one more thing. I ran across this sentence: the congress voted approval. I guess I could change it to "the plan was voted approval". Does this sentence works better than the "the plan was voted approved?"

Comment: Your sentence is probably something like "the congress voted approval *of the measure*. They "*voted approval* ***of*** *something*.", you cut the sentence off too early. An alternative would be "the plan **was approved** *by a vote of 9 to 4.*"

Answer (score -1):

Use this:   The plan was **voter approved**.

Edited: Ok, good point, here's the reason.

"The plan was voter approved" means that the plan was approved by the voters.  Some plans may not need to be approved by voters and then perhaps  "The plan was commision approved."  would be appropriate.

"Voter" modifies "approved" in the same way that "overwhelmingly" modifies "approved" in the following: 
The plan was overwhelmingly approved.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.